# SyntaxError 255 On List

Tags: python, syntax

In this piece of code:

```
n = int(input())

for i in the range(0, n):
    x = input()

    for y in range(0, len(string)):

        if y % 2 == 0:
            print(string[y], end='')

    print("", end='')

    for y in range(0, len(string)):

        if y % 2 != 0:
            print(string[y], end='')

    print("")
```

Don't know why it came so messed up.

Error:
  File "solution.py", line 3
    for i in the range(0, n):
                     ^
SyntaxError: invalid syntax

Answer (score 3):

"in the range" is not legal Python.
Remove "the".

You have a variety of other problems in the code.  I strongly recommend that you adopt *incremental programming*, especially at this stage.  Start by writing a couple of lines of code, just enough to do something, such as read and print an integer.  Once those lines work, *then* add a couple more that run through a trivial `for` loop.  Continue this, a couple of lines at a time, adding just one "baby step" to your program, seeing minor successes as you go.  For instance, start with

```
n = int(input("How many times?")
print "n=", n
```

Next, add the loop:

```
for i in range(0, n):
    print "i=", i
```

Then go on to the serial input -- again, properly labeled:

```
    x = input("Give me number", i)
    print x, type(x)
```

See how this works?

Comment: Ah. Thank you for the help.

Answer (score 0):

There are a few errors in your code . The variable"x" name should be 'strings', if you dont change it's name those for wont do anything and a previous error with the for.

```
for i in range(0,n):
    strings=input()
    for y in range(0,len(strings)):
         #the code....
```